# Latex changing lowercase with uppercase in a text

Tags: pdf, small-caps

I'm new in Latex. My problem is that Latex changing lowercase letter with uppercase letter when convert my text to pdf.

I am writting my thesis. Only have two pages. The first page is done all in uppercase, but the next not.

This is my code used. Thank for you help.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{anysize} %%para escribir los margenes con marginsize
\marginsize{2cm}{2cm}{2cm}{2cm}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}
\thispagestyle{empty}

    \vspace{2.5cm}
    \begin{center}

        \textsc {\huge INSTITUTO TECNOL'OGICO Y DE ESTUDIOS SUPERIORES DE MONTERREY}

    \vspace{0.06cm}
        \textsc {\Large CAMPUS MONTERREY}

    \vspace{0.06cm}
        \textsc {\Large ESCUELA DE BIOTECNOLOG'IA Y ALIMENTOS}

    \vspace{0.06cm}
        \textsc {\Large PROGRAMA DE GRADUADOS EN BIOTECNOLOG'IA}

    \end{center}

    \vspace {4.4cm} 
        \includegraphics[height=0.42in,width=0.42in]{/Users/JoseA/Documents/Maestria/Tesis/LogoTEC.png} 

    \vspace{0.8cm}
    \begin{center}
        \textbf {\large ``SUSCEPTIBILIDAD A LA FORMACI'ON DEL PORO DE LA TRANSICI'ON A LA PERMEABILIDAD MITOCONDRIAL EN CORAZONES DE RATAS CON S'INDROME METAB'OLICO: PARTICIPACI'ON DEL TRANSLOCADOR DE ADENIN NUCLE'OTIDOS Y SIRTUINA-3''}

    \vspace{2.2cm}
        \textsc {\large TESIS PRESENTADA COMO REQUISITO PARCIAL PARA OBTENER EL GRADO DE:}

    \vspace{0.2cm}
        \textbf {\large MAESTRO EN CIENCIAS CON ESPECIALIDAD EN BIOTECNOLOG'IA}

    \vspace{2.4cm}
        \textsc {\large POR:}

    \vspace{0.2cm}
        \textbf {\large JOS'E ALBERTO MORALES DE LOS SANTOS}

    \vspace{2.4cm}
        \textsc {\large MONTERREY, N.L.     \hfill      AGOSTO DEL 2013.}

    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}

        \textbf {\Large ``SUSCEPTIBILIDAD A LA FORMACI'ON DEL PORO DE LA TRANSICI'ON A LA PERMEABILIDAD MITOCONDRIAL EN CORAZONES DE RATAS CON S'INDROME METAB'OLICO: PARTICIPACI'ON DEL TRANSCOLADOR DE ADENIN NUCLE'OTIDOS Y SIRTUINA-3''}

    \vspace{4.0cm}
        \textsc {\Large TESIS PRESENTADA POR:}

    \vspace{1.0cm}
        \textbf {\Large JOS'E ALBERTO MORALES DE LOS SANTOS}

    \vspace{4.0cm}
        \textsc {\large ANTE EL INSTITUTO TECNOL'OGICO Y DE ESTUDIOS SUPERIORES DE MONTERREY COMO REQUISITO PARCIAL PARA OBTENER EL GRADO ACAD'EMICO DE:}

    \vspace{0.2cm}
        \textbf {\large MAESTRO EN CIENCIAS CON ESPECIALIDAD EN BIOTECNOLOG'IA}

    \vspace{4.0cm}
        \textsc {\large Monterrey, N.L.     \hfill   Agosto del 2013.}

    \newpage

    \textbf {\normalsize INSTITUTO TECNOL'OGICO DE ESTUDIOS SUPERIORES DE MONTERREY}

    \textbf {\normalsize CAMPUS MONTERREY}

    \textbf {\normalsize ESCUELA DE BIOTECNOLOG'IA Y ALIMENTOS}

    \textbf {\normalsize PROGRAMA DE GRADUADOS EN BIOTECNOLOG'IA}

    \vspace{1.5cm}  
    \textsc {\normalsize Los miembros del comit'e de tesis recomendamos que el presente proyecto de tesis presentado por}
    \textbf {\normalsize Jos'e Alberto Morales de los Santos,}
    \textsc {\normalsize sea aceptado como requisito parcial para obtener el grado acad'emico de}
    \textbf {\normalsize Maestro en Ciencias con Especialidad en Biotecnolog'ia}

    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Kindly consider using your name as user name, instead of a dull user34917. :-)

Comment: One reason you may have capital letters where you don't expect is that `\textsc{...}` converts text to small caps. If you remove those where you don't want capital letters, does it fix your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You should not do this

```
    \textbf {\large ``SUSCEPTIBILIDAD A LA FORMACI'ON DEL PORO DE LA TRANSICI'ON A LA PERMEABILIDAD MITOCONDRIAL EN CORAZONES DE RATAS CON S'INDROME METAB'OLICO: PARTICIPACI'ON DEL TRANSLOCADOR DE ADENIN NUCLE'OTIDOS Y SIRTUINA-3''}

\vspace{2.2cm}
    \textsc {\large TESIS PRESENTADA COMO REQUISITO PARCIAL PARA OBTENER EL GRADO DE:}

\vspace{0.2cm}
    \textbf {\large MA
```

as the `}` from the `\textbf` or `\textsc` ends the scope of the fontsize change before the paragraph ends so you will get large text set on a small baseline and uneven line spacing. Just use `\large` once at the start of your `center` environment, and make sure there is a blank line before the end of the environment, so that the `\large` line spacing is used correctly. To avoid using small caps, just don't use `\textsc`.